# Android - Swipe doesnt work on scrollView

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, swipe

i have sliding tabs and each tab has a scrollView,but i cannot swipe on scrollView's area,it only lets me to swipe outside of the scrollView layout.

Edit:Layout xml added.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:background="#f5f5f5" >

   <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Sepet Girişi"
    android:textColor="#b7102f"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/tvCart">
  </TextView>

   <ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/viewflipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="380dp"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    android:clickable="true">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:text="Üst Bilgiler"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:background="#2F4F4F"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/tvTopInfos"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Açık Sepetler"
                android:id="@+id/tvOpenBasket"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvTopInfos"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerOpenBasket"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:prompt="@string/search_hint"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvOpenBasket"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sepet Tipi"
            android:id="@+id/tvBasketType"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerOpenBasket"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerBasketType"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvBasketType"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sepet Adı"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/tvBasketName"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerBasketType"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etBasketName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvBasketName"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvBasketName"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Özel Notlar"
            android:id="@+id/tvSpecialNotes"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"

            android:layout_below="@+id/tvBasketName"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etSpecialNotes"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvBasketName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvSpecialNotes"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvSpecialNotes"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Fatura Müşterisi"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/tvBillCustomer"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etSpecialNotes"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Teslimat Tipi"
            android:id="@+id/tvDeliveryType"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvBillCustomer"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvBasketName"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tvBasketName" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerDeliveryType"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvDeliveryType"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="30dp"
            android:text="Teslimat Notları"
            android:id="@+id/tvDeliveryNotes"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerDeliveryType"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etDeliveryNotes"
            android:paddingTop="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerDeliveryType"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvDeliveryNotes"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvDeliveryNotes"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"  />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/etDeliveryNotes"
            android:layout_weight="100"
            android:id="@+id/llDates1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Sipariş Tarihi"
                android:id="@+id/tvOrderDate"
                android:layout_below="@+id/etDeliveryNotes"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Teslim Tarihi"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:id="@+id/tvDeliveryDate"

                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />



   </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/datePickerOrderDate"
            android:layout_below="@+id/llDates1"
             />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/datePickerDeliveryDate"
            android:layout_below="@+id/llDates1"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Son Teslim Tarihi"
            android:id="@+id/tvLastDeliveryDate"
            android:layout_below="@+id/datePickerDeliveryDate"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/datePickerLastDeliveryDate"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvLastDeliveryDate"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ödeme Tarihi"
            android:id="@+id/tvPaymentDate"
            android:layout_below="@+id/datePickerLastDeliveryDate"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/datePickerPaymentDate"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvPaymentDate"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="İstenen Fatura Tarihi"
            android:id="@+id/tvRequestedBillDate"
            android:layout_below="@+id/datePickerPaymentDate"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/datePickerRequestedBillDate"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvRequestedBillDate"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

**first tabs ending.
second tab beginning**

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:text="Teslimat"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="#2F4F4F"

                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:id="@+id/tvDeliveryInfo"

                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Teslimat Adresi"
                android:id="@+id/tvDeliveryAddress"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvDeliveryInfo"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinnerDeliveryAddress"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvDeliveryAddress"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Adres Adı"
                android:id="@+id/tvAddressName"
                android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerDeliveryAddress"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/etAddressName"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvAddressName"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ülke"
                android:id="@+id/tvCountry"
                android:layout_below="@+id/etAddressName"/>

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinnerCountry"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvCountry"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="İl"
                android:id="@+id/tvCity"
                android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerCountry"/>

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinnerCity"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvCity"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="İlçe"
                android:id="@+id/tvTown"
                android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerCity"/>

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinnerTown"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvTown"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Mahalle"
                android:id="@+id/tvDistrict"
                android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerTown"/>

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinnerDistrict"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvDistrict"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Cadde/Sokak"
                android:id="@+id/tvStreet"
                android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerDistrict"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />


            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/etStreet"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvStreet"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />




        </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Please post the xml of the layout.

Comment: @BasvanStein i added xml layout.

Answer (score 0):

That is how it is supposed to be. If you could swipe the tab even within the ScrollView, you wouldn't be able to scroll the contents of the scrollview. The ScrollView captures the motion and consumes it, and thus the tab doesn't get swiped.

Comment: but it works fine on facebook,swarm,instagram etc. they all have scrollViews and tabs.

Comment: They do have scrollviews and tabs. If you were able to swipe even within a scrollview and change tab, how would you see the full contents of a scrollview?

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to the fact that your scrollView intercepts touch. It is necessary to determine scroll action. You need to create custom scrollView. And it override the method.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mStartX = event.getX();
                mStartY = event.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mStartY - event.getY() > DELTA_DISTANCE)
                    toDrug(v, getActivity());
                if (Math.abs(mStartX - event.getX()) > DELTA_DISTANCE / 2)
                    return true;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mStartX = -1;
                mStartY = -1;
        }
        return false;
    }
```